# How to get dictionary object in Mongoengine Python?

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

On querying pymongo i get a dictionary object that can be sent directly as a response to the api request. Where as mongoengine returns a Document object on querying database. So I have to parse every object before it can be sent as the response in the api.

this is how I have to query in mongoengine.

`users = User.objects(location = 'US')`

This will return me a `BaseQueryList` object which contains User model type object. Instead I need that it should return me a list of dictionary type objects of Users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `BaseQueryList` there is one method called `as_pymongo`, we can use this to get rows as `list` of `dict` like where we get `pymongo`. The following is an example

```
users = User.objects(location = 'US').as_pymongo()
```

OR

In `BaseQueryList` there are in list of `User` class objects.

In `User` class object there is one method called `_data`, this will returns data as `dict`

So you can try like following

```
users = [user._data for user in users._iter_results()]
```

It could be help you.

Comment: This is what I do now. This way i have to iterate the list of objects returned by mongo before i can send the response to the api call. Something that returns the objects as dict is what I need to findout.

Comment: I found it and update my answer. It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoengine has `to_mongo()` method that gives you Python `dict`.

```
users = User.objects(location = 'US')
users.to_mongo()
```